# List error when printing largest item using for loop

Tags: python-3.x

Goal was to search through the given list and print the largest value but it just throws up a list index out of range error

```py
a = [1, 2, 3 ,42 ,51,12,76,22]

max = a[0]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(1, len(a) + 1):
        if a[j] > a[i]:
            max = a[j]

print(max)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the inner loop:  `for j in range(1, len(a) +1):`

Remove it remove the error:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 42, 51, 12, 76, 22]

max = a[0]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(1, len(a) ):
        if a[j] > a[i]:
            max = a[j]

print(max)
# 76
```

**Results**:
The function you defined **isn't working** because you compare each element with each others. You need to compare them with the current `max` value. 
Example not working:

```
a = [76 ,1, 2, 3, 42, 51, 12, 22 ]

max_ = a[0]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(a) ):
        if a[j] > a[i]:
            max_ = a[j]
print(max_)
# 51
```

Here is a simple working solution:

```
a = [76 ,1, 2, 3, 422, 51, 12, 22,99 ]
# Init max
max_ = a[0]
for elt in a[1:]:
    if elt > max_:
        max_ = elt
print(max_)
# 422
```

And if you want to check your results:

```
print(max(a))
#  422
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop ends one too late. But nested loops are not needed at all. A sufficient pattern would be:

```
mx = a[0]  # do not shadow built-in function

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] > mx:
        mx = a[i]
print(mx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you are using looping for this problem? The quickest way to get the result would be to use the `max` function.

Like so:

```
a = [1, 2, 3 ,42 ,51,12,76,22]
print(max(a))
```

Comment: Just figuring out how nested for loops work. Thats all.